# Insert multiple data in database at once

Tags: php, mysql

I have this code which permits me to insert some dates i've selected in a database, now this one inserts just one value, not all, it's like it stops at the first value..

Could you please tell me what i'm doing wrong?

Thanks!

```
$job_id=$_REQUEST['job_id'];

$dates = explode(",", $_POST['altField']);
foreach($dates as $date){
$sql="INSERT INTO date (job_id,date) VALUES('$job_id','$date')";
mysql_query($sql);
}
```

Comment: What is $job_id ? Is it a primary key of your table?

Comment: What is the definition of `date` table?  Is `job_id` perhaps a primary key column?

Comment: $job_id is the data passed from an input which has a format like this: 
9/10/29,9/10/2011, etc etc

Comment: Note that you should not use the `mysql_*` functions in your code. These functions are no longer maintained and are [being deprecated](http://news.php.net/php.internals/53799). Instead, you should be using either [MySQLi](http://php.net/mysqli) or [PDO](http://php.net/pdo). Don't know which to use? [This article](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqlinfo.api.choosing.php) should help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$job_id=$_REQUEST['job_id'];

$dates = explode(",", $_POST['altField']);
foreach($dates as $date){
    $values .= '("'.$job_id.'","'.$date.'"),';
}
$sql="INSERT INTO date (job_id,date) VALUES " . substr($values, 0, -1);
mysql_query($sql);
```

Inserts can have multiple value sets so you just need to set the values in the foreach and then outside of it, do the query.   you can also do it this way and get the same result,

```
$job_id=$_REQUEST['job_id'];

$dates = explode(",", $_POST['altField']);
foreach($dates as $date){
    $values[] = '("'.$job_id.'","'.$date.'")';
}
$sql="INSERT INTO date (job_id,date) VALUES " . implode(',',$values);
mysql_query($sql);
```

**REMINDER**

ALWAYS sanitize your inputs.  Not doing so could lead to SQL Injections and cause major issues for you.  Look at [this](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-real-escape-string.php)  Also mysql is not maintained and is suggested to switch to MySqli or PDO.

Comment: How is this technically any different, i.e., why is it more likely to work than the original? If you read the OP's first sentence, their problem is *not* that they want to insert all the values at once.  The problem is the first value is all that ever gets inserted with their current code.

Comment: You have the right idea, but multiple row insertions should be separated by commas. Make `$values` an array and `implode()` it at the end.

Comment: if you look it is seperated by comma's    im updating the code right now to remove the last comma

Comment: Hey, thanks for the reply, if i insert this code it doesn't work anymore, it won't take any value..

Comment: Remember to sanitize your inputs. This example doesn't do that crucial step, leaving you open to SQL injection attacks.

Comment: I am leaving that step to the user.... it is a good reminder however not supplied in the question.  I have updated the answer and reminded the user to do so.

Comment: your code has many mistakes i edited it but you rolled  it back.

Comment: Hey, thanks! the problem is that it says that there's the wrong syntax to use near implode(',',array) ..

Comment: @blerta please see fix in question... I just had the implode in the quotes.  should take it out.

Answer (score 1):

```
$job_id=$_REQUEST['job_id'];

$dates = explode(",", $_POST['altField']);
$values_arr = array();    
foreach ($dates as $date) {
    $values_arr[] = "('" . $job_id . "','" . $date . "')";
}
$values = implode(", ", $values_arr);

$sql="INSERT INTO date (job_id,date) VALUES $values";
mysql_query($sql);
```

Comment: i tried to help you by editing your answer but you rejected my correction. i had to post my original response here, even before you've fixed your answer. I am sorry for that.

Comment: You tried to completely rewrite my question... It was not just me that rejected it either

Answer (score -1):

try:

```
$sql = "INSERT INTO date SET job_id='".$job_id."', date='".$date."'";
mysql_query($sql);
```

Comment: You've combined the `INSERT` and `UPDATE` syntax, this is completely wrong...  **Edit:** Dope!  Nevermind, [it is correct for MySQL](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/insert.html)!  Sorry about that.

Comment: Oo but I use that all the time and it works, maybe I should change it. Thank you for your advice

Comment: @Touki: Whoops.  Learn something new every day :)  OK. I take my downvote back, but this is not standard T-SQL and really does nothing to address the problem.  Most people (like me) are going to have a gut reaction because we grew up with `INSERT INTO VALUES (...)` and `UPDATE SET ..` as the standard syntax which works in almost all RDBMS's.

Comment: even if it did work... this still does one query for each..  the example above does one query for all